# Pandas read_excel gives yes no while reading an excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

Using pandas to read an excel. I know its straightforward, but the dataframe output is just yes and no.

Regarding the excel file, just 11 columns with normal data, single sheet, with sheet name as Sheet1

```
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: data = pd.read_excel('/path/fileName.xlsx')

In [4]: data
Out[4]:
    No
0  Yes
```

Using Python 3.6.10 (default, May 24 2020, 21:54:41) and IPython 6.5.0.

Things i have already tried:

1. Copied the data from this given excel to a new excel file and tried reading using read_excel and that worked as expected.
2. Went through Documentation
3. Searched web for some solution.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The reader will by default take the active sheet of the workbook when it was last saved - which needn't necessarily be Sheet1... have you tried explicitly passing the sheet name you want... eg: `df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')`?

Comment: The excel file just has a single sheet. As mentioned, when i give sheet_name, it works. But ideally since we dont give any parameters, it should default to the first sheet right?

Comment: It defaults to `sheet_name=0` meaning get the first sheet. Seems like the data is not on the first sheet as you expect

Comment: Actually, the data is in the first sheet and the only sheet. Thats why it is so confusing. Any idea why it would give yes and no as output?

Comment: @raccoon the sheet is hidden?

Comment: Sheet is not hidden

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem when I started importing excel files into Ipython but I was able to fix it after some time.

Try the following:

In [1]: `import pandas`

In [2]: `import pandas as pd`

In [3]: `df = pd.read_excel(r'/path/fileName.xlsx', sheet_name =0)`

```
df.head()
```

Make sure you add letter r just like I did above before the data path on your PC.

Second method:

```
import openpyxl as op
from openpyxl import load_workbook

df = load_workbook(r"path of your dataset in your PC", sheet_name = 0)

df.head()
```

The above will show what you have in the first worksheet. Repeat same code and change sheet_name = 1, 2, 3,...... to view others.

Comment: Adding `r ` does not make any difference in this example, see https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals . It changes the way Python handles escape sequences, like `\n` and is useful when using windows paths with backslashes.